# Gnome 3 desktop environment

Tags: gnome

After taking the regular update through the update manager my gnome-shell doesn't work,

I am working on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and I have uninstalled and re-installed but the same issue persists.

Please help.

Comment: Your question doesn't really explain what the problem is. Please could you edit your question to describe symptoms?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps some of the needed packages were not installed. I would advise re-installing gnome, **without** removing it first. This way you will only download the pieces you are missing.

sudo apt-get install gnome (Entire Gnome Desktop + Pre-Installed Programs, **if you are unsure, pick this one**)

or

sudo apt-get install gnome-shell (Just Gnome Desktop)

sincerely, tapthoseshoesandwish

sources: http://candlelight.any.djun.net/x/1/index.php?topic=576.0

Answer (score 0):

Inasmuch as I understand your problem, try this...

At the login screen click the little Ubuntu "foot logo", and use another desktop.
When logged in, run Update Manager.
Stick with that desktop for a bit, and keep up to date using Update Manager.
Eventually you may be able to login using the Gnome 3 environment.

I had trouble getting Gnome 3 going, and this is all I did - eventually it fixed itself !